# How can I help Clojure understand that 0 is the smallest natural number?

Tags: clojure, mathematical-optimization, relation, minimum, datomic

It's easy to define a lazy sequence of natural numbers in Clojure: `(def N (iterate inc 0))`. Unsurprisingly, if we ask Clojure to find the minimum of N using `(apply min N)`, it gets stuck in an infinite regress.

Is there a way to "build in" the fact that `(= 0 (min N))` to the data structure of N? Implicitly, *we* know this, since the increment function `inc` is strictly increasing. The `min` function doesn't know how to exploit this knowledge, and instead tries to brute force its way to the answer.

I don't know how to encode this programmatically. I would like a way to construct lazy sequences with additional structure like constraints & relations). I would also like a way to exploit these constraints in order to solve optimization problems (like finding the minimum or infimum of the sequence).

Is there a way to do this in native Clojure? What about with [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com)?

Comment: Where does Datomic fit into this? Are you trying to store that extra constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use metadata for the specific example you have.

```
(defn my-range
  ([] (my-range 0))
  ([n] (with-meta
         (cons n (lazy-seq (my-range (inc n))))
         {:onlyincreases true})))

(defn my-min [x] (if (:onlyincreases (meta x)) (first x) (min x)))

(my-min (my-range)) ;; => 0
(my-min (next (my-range))) ;; => 1
(my-min (nnext (my-range))) ;; => 2
```

If you need something more generalized, you might have to look into creating your own type.